# PhpStorm splits arrow operator on code cleanup

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

I have a foreach inside a JavaScript script tag like this:

```
stores_li.forEach((item) => {                              
    document.getElementById('hide').appendChild(item);
    item.classList.remove('active-store');
}
```

Every time I run the code cleaner command, PhpStorm adds a space between `=>` so my code is now:

```
stores_li.forEach((item) = > {                              
    document.getElementById('hide').appendChild(item);
    item.classList.remove('active-store');
}
```

This throws an error on my console and breaks my code.

Any workaround to solve this? Any preference on PhpStorm?

Comment: What Language Level is set for JavaScript? Does IDE complains about the original code in any away? If `=>` is properly recognized as arrow function by IDE then it should not be splitting it up.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you! That was the problem :) I changed the JavaScript version to ECMAScript 6 (5.1 was selected) and now it recognized all my code :)

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrade.**

Older versions of PHPStorm did not have support for Arrow functions in Code Style Preferences and were confusing your arrow function with two relational operators.

In PHPStorm preferences you can define spacing around operators per language.

**For instance if you go to:**

*Preferences -> Code Style -> Javascript* and click the 'Spaces' tab, you can see how the IDE handles spacing around particular operators.

This window also gives you the ability to paste in your own code and toggle options to see how changes effect your code.

**Version 10.0.4**

This first screenshot is from PHPStorm 10.0.4 and as you can see there is no option for Arrow Functions.

[image]

**EAP 2017.3**

This second screenshot is from the [EAP 2017.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/) version which does support arrow functions. So it seems like upgrading would be the solution to your issue.

[image]

Comment: Hi @robert .  Thank you for such detailed information :)
I'm actually running 2017.2 version and the Arrow Functions already exist:
https://imgur.com/a/sVhx0
Should I just remove the selection?

Comment: Well I can’t really say without seeing everything in your prefs. I’d recommend pasting your code in the prefs pane And trying different configurations until you find what works. Good luck!

Comment: It is still happening in my 2017.3 version. Somehow, Phpstorm adds a space in between the arrow operator. And, the only way I can fix it is by manually formatting the code.